# How to Use Count for getting total from one column against other column of same table in Power BI?

Tags: count, report, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and need some help. I have a table of opportunities in which one column has name principals and one is with name status of the opportunity having values like Won, Lost, Open. Now i want to get the total count of Won Opportunities against each principal. How can i do this? Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

First create a measure to calculate the "Won" count:

```
Total Won Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[Opportunities]), FILTER(Table, Table[Opportunities] = "Won"))
```

Then use this measure against each name principal.

I hope this helps!